# Firebase analytics label doesn't get shown in the firebase console

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I have a project that uses Firebase to send push notifications. However, the analytics label field doesn't get shown in Reports.

I've tried changing notification structure in various ways, but it doesn't seem to get me everywhere. API requests to fcmdata.googleapis.com don't show any presence of analytics label either. And yet, everything related to message delivery seems to be working just fine. What could possibly go wrong?